# How do I make use of a "header only (.hpp)" library as a component?

Tags: esp32

I am trying to include a library that uses files such as blah.hpp as a "component" and have them compiled using the esp32 idf.

I created a components sub directory in the project, and copied the library into a sub directory of the components directory.  if I use a boiler plate `component.mk` file the files with the .hpp suffix are not seen by the compiler.  If I rename a file such as `blah.hpp` to `blah.cpp` the compiler does see the `blah.cpp` file,  so it's just not seeing the files with the `.hpp` suffix

I tried adding the following the the component.mk file (which I noticed [here](https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/blob/master/make/component_wrapper.mk)) but then I got the following error.

```
make[1]: *** No rule to make target '/home/john/development/esp/ble_test2/components/rxcpp/./rx-sources.o', needed by 'librxcpp.a'.  Stop.
```

Here is the component.mk file (with the added line I mentioned above) I am trying to use.

```
#
# Main component makefile.
#
# This Makefile can be left empty. By default, it will take the sources in the 
# src/ directory, compile them and link them into lib(subdirectory_name).a 
# in the build directory. This behaviour is entirely configurable,
# please read the ESP-IDF documents if you need to do this.
COMPONENT_ADD_INCLUDEDIRS=.
COMPONENT_OBJS += $(foreach compsrcdir,$(COMPONENT_SRCDIRS),$(patsubst %.hpp,%.o,$(wildcard $(COMPONENT_PATH)/$(compsrcdir)/*.hpp)))

## Uncomment the following line to enable exception handling 
CXXFLAGS+=-fexceptions
CXXFLAGS+= -std=c++11
```

This seems like a simple thing to fix,  I do see components in the esp32 idf that also use files such as blah.hpp, for example [here](https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/tree/master/components/nvs_flash/src), but I can't what option I need to set to enable mine to compile.

btw,  not sure if it's a good idea to try and use rxcpp on a an esp32, but I am curious if it would even work :)

Answer (score 1):

The same way that you include any header file - just `#include` it in an appropriate `.cpp` file. If you're using a Makefile, be sure to add a dependency on the `.hpp` file to the object file produced by the `.cpp` file just as you would for a `.h` file and a `.c` file.

Don't try to use rxcpp as a component. It's not meant to be built as a library. Like the repo says, it's header-only. You just `#include` it where you need it.

Comment: in the esp-idf it seems the intent is to provide libraries as "components",  which are compiled separately into a library,  perhaps using unique compiler flags for example, and then the component libraries are linked to the main application.  I would still need need to include the header file for the definitions, but the implementation should be provided via the linking step.  The first problem I am having is that the compiling of the "component" does not seem to recognize the .hpp files.  So I am not sure how this is supposed to work.

Comment: I am guessing the next problem will be how I tell the compiler to just pick up the definitions from the .hpp files and not try to compile the implementation.

Comment: You're trying to fit a round peg into a square hole by trying to build it as a component. rxcpp is not normally used as a library. Create a minimal ESP32 test program for yourself, get rxcpp in the include search path and  "#include "rxcpp/rx.hpp"" in main or anywhere you're calling it from. That's the way rxcpp is designed to be used.

Comment: I realized I was over thinking this last night.  In fact the COMPONENT_OBJS line I added only made things more confusing.  In the end I inserted the src by adding  'COMPONENT_ADD_INCLUDEDIRS=../../../RxCpp/Rx/v2/src' to the existing component.mk file in the 'main' directory.  If there is a more proper way to get the library into the include path,  or you think the way I did it is correct,  please add that info to your answer and I will accept it.